# javascript slideshow that loads new page after last slide

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Sorry, I'm quite new to JS. I have a basic html page where I've put in a slideshow that advances the slide with each click. What I want to have happen is have it change to a new page when the user clicks next and is on the last slide. My html:

```
<div id="images">
    <img id="image1" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/960/580/sports" />
    <img id="image2" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/960/580/cats" />
    <img id="image3" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/960/580/food" />
    <img id="image4" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/960/580/people" />
</div>
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
var max = 4;

function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/image/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#image", ""));
        (newh > max - 1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#image" + String(newh + 1);
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "image1";
    }
}

function goToPrevious() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/image/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#image", ""));
        (newh == 1) ? newh = 5 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#image" + String(newh - 1);
    } else {
   var url = window.location.href;

if (url.search("#image") > 0) {
    window.location.href = "strategy.html";
  }    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
(newh > max - 1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#image" + String(newh + 1);
```

to this:

```
(newh > max - 1) ? window.location.href = "strategy.html" :
        document.location.hash = "#image" + String(newh + 1);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/4QnDp/)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if newh is zero,

```
    if(newh == 0) 
        document.location.href = "strategy.html";
```

Here is the all code, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FXrs6/4/)

```
var max = 4;

function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/image/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#image", ""));
        (newh > max - 1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);

        if(newh == 0) 
            document.location.href = "strategy.html";
        else 
            document.location.hash = "#image" + String(newh + 1);
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "image1";
    }
}

function goToPrevious() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/image/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#image", ""));
        (newh == 1) ? newh = max+1 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#image" + String(newh - 1);
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "image4";    
 }
}
```